# Issue with @Value annotation in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, shared-libraries

I am working on one library and the library has a model class like following

`class Model { Object a; }`

To use the model I have created a wrapper class like this

```
@Configuration
class ModelWrapper {
 private Object a;
 
@Autowired 
<Bean> b;

void setA(Object a){
this.a =a;

}
Object getA(){
return this.a; 
}
}
```

This bean b , it interacts with configurable environment and store some value in properties, issue is when I autowire ModelWrapper , I can access that value I injected in env but when I do not autowire the valuModelWrapper Value annotation gives issuesand  doesn't work out, any ideas on this!?

I tried Autowiring for ModelWrapper an it worked